# React Native useEffect returned undefined value from Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to get my data on API, when i console.log for the first time, i still get the data. But when i'm trying to set it into my state, it returned undefined. What's wrong with my code?

````
```

    useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`https://angga605090.herokuapp.com/homeicon`)
      .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          setHomeIcon(res.data)
          console.log(homeicon)
      }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
      })
},[])


const [homeicon,setHomeIcon]=useState()

```
````

when i console. log, my data looks like this:

```
[{"id": 1, "img": "https://titan.email/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/email-introduction.png", "name": "Memperkenalkan Diri"}, {"id": 2, "img": "https://cdn.wpforms.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/thank-you-page-examples.jpg", "name": "Mengucapkan Terima Kasih"}, {"id": 3, "img": "https://media.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2018/03/27233542/powerful-daily-routine.001-370x208@2x.jpeg", "name": "Kegiatan Sehari-hari"}, {"id": 4, "img": "https://www.goodnewsfromindonesia.id/uploads/post/large-maxresdefault-6-b21cac43d55730ce33a5e9d52af656dd.jpg", "name": "Pengenalan Angka"}, {"id": 5, "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/southfloridareporter/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/17080327/days-of-the-year-logo.jpg", "name": "Pengenalan Hari"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state is asynchronous so changes can not be seen immediatelly.

See: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

You can do the following in order to see the state change:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`https://angga605090.herokuapp.com/homeicon`)
      .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          setHomeIcon(res.data)
          // console.log(homeicon) <-- remove that line
      }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
      })
},[])

useEffect(() => {   <-- add this hook
  console.log(homeicon);
},[homeicon])
```

Comment: Its not an answer, at best a comment

Comment: I edited the answer in order to give a solution to the problem.